# Node.js: How to setup different variables for prod and staging

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, express

I'm using Express and I need to use different credentials for each server (staging and production).

I could setup the variables in the server.coffee file but then I'd need to access those variables in different files.

```
server.coffee:

app.configure 'production', () ->
 app.use express.errorHandler()
```

What's the solution? Setup the variables and then export them?

Answer (score 20):

**./config.js**

```
var development = {
  appAddress : '127.0.0.1:3000',
  socketPort : 4000,
  socketHost : '127.0.0.1',
  env : global.process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
};

var production = {
  appAddress : 'someDomain.com',
  socketPort : 4000,
  socketHost : '8.8.8.8',
  env : global.process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'
};

exports.Config = global.process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? production : development;
```

**./app.js**

```
var cfg = require('./config').Config;

if (cfg.something) { // switch on environment
  // your logic
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the app.js code. I set the variables in the config.js but then, how can I "read" them in my app.js?

Comment: The last line in ./config.js allows you to export that code to your ./app.js file. ./config.js returns the appropriate json object depending on your environment, and then you set the variable cfg to that json object. One mistake, though. config.something should be cfg.something because that's the name of the variable that you're creating.

Comment: Make sure you set the `NODE_ENV` config variable on your production server. With Heroku it'd be `heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production`. Without doing so, the last line of `config.js` won't work.

Comment: How would this work? I assume you don't want to check your development config stuff into version control, and to do that you'd have to add this file to `.gitignore` (or equivalent). But then how would the production server get access to it? It seems to me that you'd have to separate it into two files for this reason.

Answer (score 6):

This might be a good place to use [npm-config](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-config.html).

> When running scripts (see npm-scripts(7)) the package.json "config" keys are overwritten in the environment if there is a config param of `<name>[@<version>]:<key>`

I would not use them for every type of variable configuration setting, but I think it's a good solution for simple cases like URLs and ports because:

1. You put them directly into package.json.
2. In addition, you can specify them on the command line or as ENV variables.
3. Anything run through npm can refer to them (e.g., scripts).
4. You can set them per-user with `npm config set foo:port 80

The one caveat is that the `config` parameter in your package.json is only automatically exported into the environment when you run your code through npm. So, if you just run it with node, like, `node ./myapp.js`, then you can't expect that `process.env.npm_package_config_foo` will contain your value. However, you can always `var pkg = require('./package.json');` and access the values at `pkg.config`.

Because it might not be immediately obvious, I'd also add that the `npm_package_config` environment variables do not bubble up to apps that depend on your npm package. So, if your depended-on package refers to `process.env.npm_package_config_foo`, then the dependent package would have to define that in its own package.json. I guess since it's an "npm_package_config" it wouldn't make sense to push them all the way up the tree.

So, how would I use one npm config variable and have it work all the way up the tree, in both the base package and the packages that depend on it? It's actually a little confusing, and I had to figure this out through trial and error.

Let's say you have a package *connector* and package *client*. *client* depends on *connector* and you want to specify a config parameter for *connector* that can be used or overwritten in *client*. If you use `process.env.npm_package_config.port` in your *connector* module, then when it's depended on in *client* module, then that variable won't be exported and it will end up as undefined.

However, if you instead use `process.env.npm_config_connector_port` (notice the first one starts with *npm_package_config* and the other with *npm_config_packagename*), then you can at least set that in your .npmrc using `npm config set connector:port 80` and it will be "namespaced" as `process.env.npm__config_connector_port` everywhere that you run npm, including scripts that you run in *client* that depend on *connector*, and you'll always be able to overwrite it on the command line, in your ENV, or in your .npmrc. You just have to keep in mind that, as with any environment variable, it may not always be set. So, I would use the default operator with the `process.env.npm_config_connector_port` as the first (preferred) value:

`var port = process.env.npm_config_connector_port || sane_default`

Here, *sane_default* could be populated from one of the other recommended methods. Personally, I like keeping configuration data like these in JSON files at the very least, and *package.json* seems like the best JSON file to put them in. Store them in data instead of code and then you can easily use the static JSON in-line, generate them dynamically, or pull them from the filesystem, URLs or databases.

Answer (score 2):

I have uploaded an implementation into https://github.com/qiangyu/nodejsconfig. I believe it will satisfy your needs. Basically, you only need to provide one configuration file:

```
dev.appAddress = '127.0.0.1:3000';
prod.appAddress = 'someDomain.com';
```

Then, you use following code to read the appAddress in prod environments:

```
var xnconfig = require('nodejsconfig');
var fs = require('fs');

var data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+"/config.properties", "UTF8");

// assume we will be using environment "prod"
var config = xnconfig.parse("prod", data);

// the output will be someDomain.com
console.log(config.getConfig("appAddress"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the logic for determining which config to use in each file (which would look pretty ugly), you'll have to export it somewhere.

What I would suggest: Have a `config.json` file containing the different configs. The main file requires it and does something like `config.default = config.(condition ? 'production':'development')`. In all other files, you can now just do `require('./config').default`.

Answer (score 1):

I have an app which uses three different methods of declaring config variables (uris, api keys, credentials, etc.) depending upon the environment (production = environment variables; staging = command line args; local = config files.)
I wrote a little "config" module to handle merging all of these options into one object that I can use in my app and uploaded it as a gist: https://gist.github.com/1616583

It might not be the best implementation, but it's been working pretty well so far :).