# Can I chain npm configuration entries?

Tags: node.js, configuration, build, npm

Use of the `npm` `config` section is simple, and cool, but I've run into one restriction with it: a config entry does not get expanded, so one cannot chain them, nor even access non-config values s.a. package version within the config.

Sample:

```
{
  "name": "myproj",
  "version": "0.1.2",

  "//": "Here, '$npm_package_version' is not expanded",
  "config": {
    "target": "dist/myproj-$npm_package_version.js"
  },

  "scripts": {
    "echo": "echo $npm_package_config_target",
  }
}
```

This gives:

`dist/myproj-$npm_package_version.js`

instead of:

`dist/myproj-0.1.2.js`

Is there anything I can do about it? Chaining values like this is a useful feature - I'm surprised `nom` doesn't do it. Is there a reason not to?

References:

- [Node.js: How to setup different variables for prod and staging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867055/node-js-how-to-setup-different-variables-for-prod-and-staging)
- [How to use npm as a build tool](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few of ways this could be handled.

The simplest way is probably just to eval the string

```
{
    "name": "myproj",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "config": {
        "target": "dist/myproj-$npm_package_version.js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "echo": "eval echo $npm_package_config_target"
    }
}
```

If you're not comfortable with eval then you could either manually concat the string within the script:

```
{
    "name": "myproj",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "config": {
        "target_prefix": "dist/myproj-",
        "target_suffix": ".js"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "echo": "echo $npm_package_config_target_prefix$npm_package_version$npm_package_config_target_suffix",
    }
}
```

Or you could do away with using npms `config` and write a quick script instead, which can be composed with others:

```
{
    "name": "myproj",
    "version": "0.1.2",
    "scripts": {
        "config:target": "echo dist/myproj-$npm_package_version.js",
        "echo": "echo $(npm run config:target)"
    }
}
```